# How to auto-import composables/node_modules with unplugin-vue-components package?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, auto-import

I've set up `unplugin-vue-components` which now auto-imports all `vue components` from `src` folder but it won't import `js files` (f.e. `store.js` which is located in `src/composables`). It also doesn't import `node modules` like `axios`. Any idea how to do it? I'd like it to work like `Nuxt 3 auto import` (which is awesome).

github link: [unplugin-vue-components](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components)

This is my `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
      vue(),
      Components({
          dirs: ['src'],
          extensions: ['vue', 'js']
      })
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unplugin-vue-components plugin is meant to import components. If you want to import JS files (and more specifically, JS variables) you can use this plugin: https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import

Beside the ability to import popular library like axios, you can also add your local ones using `dir` porperty.

```
 // Auto import for module exports under directories
  // by default it only scan one level of modules under the directory
  dirs: [
    // './hooks',
    // './composables' // only root modules
    // './composables/**', // all nested modules
    // ...
  ],
```

Refer to readme for more information.

Comment: I have tested this option many times - it never worked. if it works on your side, it would be helpful to show us some working examples

Comment: You can provide a minimal reproduction of what you have tried and I can check it.

Comment: I know why it was not working. Got it sorted now. Thanks! :-D

Comment: @Run Can you help me with what issue you faced?